# Facebook Like Box not adding more posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour with the Facebook Like Box.

I visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages, and I put in https://www.facebook.com/CavendishFarms for the URL, uncheck "Show Friend's Faces", and I check the "Show Posts" option.

The box comes up fine with the last two posts that have been added to the Cavendish Farms feed. However, as soon as I scroll to the bottom, the Like Box attempts to load additional posts, but fails.

I bring up Chrome's dev tools, and hundreds of requests are being made to URLs like: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox/stream?id=1475357386029603&dom=pluginLikeboxMoreStories&force_wall=false&nobootload=1&inlinecss=1&max_timestamp=1382722603&width=300&__user=100005969895272&__a=1&__dyn=042yUbFuC&__req=9&locale=en_US&__rev=1317614

I need to stop the page or refresh it to stop the Like Box from trying to get new posts.

If I use the default URL of https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers, scrolling down on the Like Box loads posts as expected.

Anyone know why my URL would be causing this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a [valid Facebook bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1480435988846221/), and it has been reported. I'm curious as to when there will be a fix as well.

Comment: It might be the same... The submitter indicated he has issues once there are no more posts left to copy over from the feed, whereas my issue is I can't load any but the first two.

Comment: You can make a comment in the bug report to provide additional information.